# Setting up nHibernate with SQLite

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, c#-4.0

Does anyone have a step-by-step guide on how to use nHibernate and SQLite? I can't figure out which dll's I need and which goes in the references and which just need to be copied. I would also like to know how to create the actual file for SQLite.

This is for a small application running .Net 4.0 - I understand some things have changed since 3.0 and NHibernate 1.2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLLs:

- NHibernate.dll
- NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll
- Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll
- Castle.Core.dll
- Antlr3.Runtime.dll
- log4net.dll
- Iesi.Collections.dll
- System.Data.SQLite.dll

Creating the db file:

- [SchemaExport.Create()](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#M:NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Create%28System.Boolean,System.Boolean%29)

Comment: And I just reference all of them in the project?

Comment: you will most likely only need to reference NHibernate.dll (and possibly Iesi.Collections.dll depending on how you build your persistent classes). you will need to copy them to your build dir so NHibernate cal load them at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a speedy reply!

Comment: I wrote a post about it on my blog. Maybe this will help you!
http://gergroen.blogspot.com/2011/11/nhibernate-getting-started-guide.html